# Creating an NSOperationQueue with an operation that will terminate if not finished in a given time

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

How do I create a `NSOperationQueue` with an operation that will time out if not completed within a given amount of time ?

Comment: Just code the operation to terminate when needed. There's nothing to do with the queue.

Comment: I am new to xCode, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: You mean you are new to Objective-C and Cocoa. The IDE you use is irrelevant to your question. It would help to know your operation is doing. Update your question with more details.

Comment: Haha true.  My apologies.  Do you recommend I put up the code in question?